# I have a webApp UI Want to transform it to mobile

Tags: mobile-application

[image: Web UI]

I have a web-app which has like the above  attached image,I want to display the same in mobile but in a meaningful and more convenient way,Need some advice for design the above in mobile.

**Description of the image/UI:**

In the Top left : There is a heading contain the `exercise name` just below that there is an `Image (Exercise image)` right to it there is the exercise `description` and below there are fields where you can add the `set 1. Number of set 2. The weight  you can add and delete the Sets respectably.`

In the down there is `Skip` and `Next` button to go next screen .

Comment: Can you be more specific about the advice you are looking for?

Comment: I want to Design the above attached UI in mobile currently its in web,I mean how to arrange those things to display in mobile properly.

Comment: Are you targeting iOS and Android?

Comment: @SteveD i am targeting both and IOS and Android and Windows at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The first step of transforming something from (as far as I can tell) desktop to mobile is to **sort your information by importance** and then presenting that information under each other, or in multiple steps.

Since you didn't give much context, I can only judge from the image. It seems like you have multiple steps, there are specific UI controls on different platforms for that:

Android: [Steppers](https://material.google.com/components/steppers.html#)
iOS: [Page Controls](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-controls/page-controls/) (I'm not sure if there's a better control for that)
Didn't find something specific for Windos Phone, but here's a [general link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/index).

Comment: All though your answer is not very accurate but some points like steppers really applicable in my app.What i was asking is how to position these elements (Like Exercise name,Exercise image,Exercise Des,Set 1,Set 2 so on so that its usability and look and feel would look good on mobile device